# Image looks blur created using RenderTargetBitamp in WPF

Tags: wpf, bitmap

In my application saving a large canvas into bitmap using WPF's RenderTargetBitmap. With large image size the image looks blur. with smaller size it works fine. I am creating bitmap with 96 dpi and the following code is used to save the canvas as bitmap.

```
RenderTargetBitmap bitamp = new RenderTargetBitmap(
                                (int)bounds.Width,
                                (int)bounds.Height,
                                96,
                                96,
                                System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

//Create Drawing Visual.
DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();

using (DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
{
    VisualBrush visualBrush = new VisualBrush(canvas);

    //Draw rectangle filled with canvas.
    drawingContext.DrawRectangle(visualBrush, null, new Rect(new Point(), bounds.Size));
}

//Render drawing visual to bitmap.
bitamp.Render(drawingVisual);

//Create instance of JpegBitmapEncoder
JpegBitmapEncoder jpgEncoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();

//Add bitmap.
jpgEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitamp));

//Create new file and get stream from that.
using (Stream stream = File.Create(fileName))
{
    //Save Image.
    jpgEncoder.Save(stream);
}
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You are saving it as a jpeg, not a bitmap. Jpeg is designed as a `lossy` file format, it will drop the quality in order to save space.  If you want a smaller `lossless` file, use png.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact conditions but JpegBitmapEncoder may produce blurred outline of elements. So I would suggest to use PngBitmapEncoder instead.

Comment: Thnak you for your answers. i tried with PngBitmapEncoder  and BmpBitmapEncoder. But the image quality is still poor. looks blurry.